How to Output and Deploy Multiple Artifacts from Best Child in Sweep Job Component?
I am building a pipeline composed of 6 components using Azure Machine Learning SDK2 Python, and I am currently working on the 4 component.
In my script, I created a Sweep Job to hyper-tune my model, which is an autoencoder. The script performs the following tasks:

Builds and trains the autoencoder
Create the Autoencoder (Trained)
Get the Encoder Layer (For analyses)
Fit standard scaler (object)
Log Metrics using mlflow

I am saving the following:

The autoencoder model
The encoder layers
The StandardScaler object (For analyses)
The ScalerAutoencoderWrapper (StandardScaler fit + keras.model.predict) mlflow.sklearn_log() raised a warning that .predict method is missing (To me, this function was built for End-to-end Pipeline + Algo from Sklearn) therefore I use a custom pyfunc from mlflow

After several job experiments, I realized that the SweepJob component automatically outputs the best child. I cannot use mlflow_model as an output because I have four different outputs, not just one (I need all four).
I thought of using uri_folder, but I'm unsure how iterate thorugh the uri_folder to get my ScalerAutoencoderWrapper or use mlflow to deploy the model in the next step
My question is:

How can I output all these folders, especially the ScalerAutoencoderWrapper, and pass it as uri_folder? Additionally
how can I use MLflow to deploy the ScalerAutoencoderWrapper in the next component while retaining the other files?

Any feedback on how the files are saved is also welcome.
Thanks a lot!
I have attached my code.

.... PARTIAL CODE ...

# Log Model
    with mlflow.start_run() as run:

# Build Model
        autoencoder, encoder = build_model(
            input_dim=input_dim,
            hidden_layers=hidden_layers,
            encoded_dim=encoded_dim,
            l1_regularizer=l1_regularizer,
            learning_rate=learning_rate,
            return_encoder=return_encoder,
        )

        # Define Strategy
        early_stopping = EarlyStopping(
            monitor=MONITOR,
            patience=patience,
            restore_best_weights=True
        )

        # Fit & Keep History
        autoencoder.fit(
            X_scaled,
            X_scaled,
            epochs=epochs,
            batch_size=batch_size,
            validation_data=(X_validate_scaled, X_validate_scaled),
            callbacks=[early_stopping, MLflowCallback()],  # Log the final validation loss
        )

        # Save Model artifacts
        input_raw_example = X_train.iloc[:5]
        input_transformed = scalerObj.fit_transform(input_raw_example)

        # Artifact Names
        scaler_pkl = 'scaler.pkl'
        encoder_folder = 'encoder'
        autoencoder_folder= 'autoencoder'
        autoencoder_wrapper_folder = 'scaler_autoencoder_wrapper'

        # Save StandardScaler Object
        print("--------------> Save Object Scaler")
        with open('scaler.pkl', "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(scalerObj, f)

        mlflow.log_artifact('scaler.pkl', run_id=run_id)

        # Save encoder layers
        print("--------------> Save Encoder")
        mlflow.keras.log_model(encoder, 'encoder', input_example=input_transformed)

        # Save Autoencoder model Only
        print("--------------> Save AutoEncoder")
        mlflow.keras.log_model(autoencoder, 'autoencoder', input_example=input_transformed)

        # Save StandardScaler + Autoencoder
        print("--------------> Save ScalerAutoencoderWrapper")
        scaler_autoencoder_wrapper = ScalerAutoencoderWrapper(
            scaler=scalerObj,
            autoencoder=autoencoder
        )

        mlflow.pyfunc.log_model(
            artifact_path='scaler_autoencoder_wrapper',
            python_model=scaler_autoencoder_wrapper,
            input_example=input_transformed,
            signature=infer_signature(
                model_input=input_transformed,
                model_output=scaler_autoencoder_wrapper.predict(
                    context=None,
                    model_input=input_raw_example
                )
            ),
        )

        print(f"Training Completed, Model and Scaler saved with id : {run_id}")

My Python code
# Create Nodes for Pipelines
@pipeline(default_compute = 'XXXX', 
          display_name="ABCDE",
          experiment_name = "EFGH",
          tags={'objective':'DONTKNOW'})
def pipeline_autoencoder(input_file):

    # Step 1: Local Feature Selection
    feature_extraction_step = feature_extraction(
        input_file = input_file,
    )

    # Step 2: Local Split Selection 
    data_split_step = data_split (
        input_file = feature_extraction_step.outputs.output_file,
    )

    # Step 3: Hyperparameter tuning (Sweep Job)
    train_model_step = train_tune_model(
        x_train=data_split_step.outputs.x_train_path,
        y_train=data_split_step.outputs.y_train_path,
        x_validate=data_split_step.outputs.x_validate_path,
        y_validate=data_split_step.outputs.y_validate_path,
        hidden_layers = Choice([str, str]),
        encoded_dim=Choice([int]),
        l1_regularizer=Choice([float, float), 
        learning_rate=Choice([float, float]),
        batch_size=Choice([int, int]),
        epochs=Choice([int, int]),
        patience=Choice([int, int]),
     
    )

    # OverWrite
    sweep_step = train_model_step.sweep(
        compute='XXXX',
        primary_metric = "METRIC",
        goal = "MINIMIZE",
        sampling_algorithm="RANDOM",
    )

    sweep_step.early_termination = BanditPolicy(
               evaluation_interval=INT,
               slack_factor=FLOAT,
                delay_evaluation=INT)

    sweep_step.set_limits(max_total_trials=INT, max_concurrent_trials=INT, timeout=INT)

    # Step 4 
    deploybestchild (NOT DONE ALREADY)

    )
    return {
        'model_output': sweep_step.outputs.model_output,
        "x_test": data_split_step.outputs.x_test_path,
        "y_test": data_split_step.outputs.y_test_path,

        
    }


I have tried to output the file from sweep job as uri_folder and got only a blob storage file encoded
I tried to Iterate using os.walk(path) but I got nothing is saying empty
I tried to follow this example Azure Hyper Parameters exmple
pehrps you can tell me why they  do this

# train model
    model = train_model(params, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)
    # Output the model and test data
    # write to local folder first, then copy to output folder

    mlflow.sklearn.save_model(model, "model")

    from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree

    # copy subdirectory example
    from_directory = "model"
    to_directory = args.model_output

    copy_tree(from_directory, to_directory)


UPDATE
update ont @JayashankarGS answer
I truly appreciate your support, but I'm currently facing an error that says either the blob storage does not exist or I get the following: yaml.representer.RepresenterError: ('cannot represent an object').
I've noticed that you have a strong reputation for resolving these types of issues. Could you assist me with the following questions?

Is the Sweep Job actually outputting the best model? I see a model with 2 Trials output, but there’s no documentation to confirm my assumption.
I'm using pyfunc.log_model. Should I switch from an MLflow model to a custom model since I’m using pyfunc? (specifically regarding YAML input/output)

outputs:
  model_ouput:
    type: **mlflow_model** or **custom_model**
    description: ....
  artifacts_output:
    type: uri_folder
    description:.....



I tried setting (as you suggested)
autoencoder_wrapper_folder = args.artifacts+'scaler_autoencoder_wrapper'`, but I encountered `yaml.representer.RepresenterError: ('cannot represent an object', PosixPath('/mnt/azureml/cr/j/ABCDE/cap/data-capability/wd/model_output/model')).

Following the Azure example:


# copy subdirectory example
from_directory = "model"
to_directory = args.model_output

copy_tree(from_directory, to_directory)

I got the error 'model is not a directory.' I then tried using os.getcwd() because i assumed my model is saved in the current dir, but I received 'No such file or directory: '/mnt/azureml/cr/j/ABCDS/exe/wd/model'.' It seems the model isn't being saved there, and I’m unsure where Azure Machine Learning is saving it.

My pipeline currently consists of Step 1, Step 2, Sweep Job -> Evaluation. For now, I’m passing the model’s .h5 file and the StandardScaler object to another component for evaluation and registration. This isn't ideal, but it's the only workaround I’ve found. I suspect pyfunc might need a different approach for saving, but I’m unsure as the documentation only provides simple examples using sweep job and Sklearn.log_model or mlflow but only with one model but not sweep + mlflow save models."


You need to log the files in the output location you configured for training component.
Below is the sample training component yaml file.
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/commandComponent.schema.json
type: command

name: train_model
display_name: train_model
version: 1

inputs: 
  data:
    type: uri_folder
  ....Your extra inputs
  max_iter:
    type: integer
    default: -1
  decision_function_shape:
    type: string
    default: ovr
  break_ties:
    type: boolean
    default: false
  random_state:
    type: integer
    default: 42

outputs:
  model_output:
    type: mlflow_model
  artifacts:
    type: uri_folder
  
code: ./train-src

environment: azureml:AzureML-sklearn-1.0-ubuntu20.04-py38-cpu@latest

command: >-
  python train.py 
  --data ${{inputs.data}}
  ...You extra arguments
  --model_output ${{outputs.model_output}}
  --artifacts ${{outputs.artifacts}}

Here, if see the outputs having the model_output and artifacts which is used to log model and save your files.
Pass these values in training component arguments like below and it will be saved.
train_model_step = train_tune_model(
        x_train=data_split_step.outputs.x_train_path,
        y_train=data_split_step.outputs.y_train_path,
        x_validate=data_split_step.outputs.x_validate_path,
        y_validate=data_split_step.outputs.y_validate_path,
        hidden_layers = Choice([str, str]),
        encoded_dim=Choice([int]),
        l1_regularizer=Choice([float, float), 
        learning_rate=Choice([float, float]),
        batch_size=Choice([int, int]),
        epochs=Choice([int, int]),
        patience=Choice([int, int]),
        model_output="Path to save model",
        artifacts="Path to save artifacts."
    )

Below the code you need to save.
        # Artifact Names
        scaler_pkl = args.artifacts+'scaler.pkl'
        encoder_folder = args.artifacts+'encoder'
        autoencoder_folder= args.artifacts+'autoencoder'
        autoencoder_wrapper_folder = args.artifacts+'scaler_autoencoder_wrapper'

        # Save StandardScaler Object
        print("--------------> Save Object Scaler")
        with open(scaler_pkl, "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(scalerObj, f)

        # Save encoder layers
        print("--------------> Save Encoder")
        mlflow.keras.log_model(encoder, encoder_folder, input_example=input_transformed)

        # Save Autoencoder model Only
        print("--------------> Save AutoEncoder")
        mlflow.keras.log_model(autoencoder, autoencoder_folder, input_example=input_transformed)

        # Save StandardScaler + Autoencoder
        print("--------------> Save ScalerAutoencoderWrapper")
        scaler_autoencoder_wrapper = ScalerAutoencoderWrapper(
            scaler=scalerObj,
            autoencoder=autoencoder
        )

        mlflow.pyfunc.log_model(
            artifact_path=autoencoder_wrapper_folder,
            python_model=scaler_autoencoder_wrapper,
            input_example=input_transformed,
            signature=infer_signature(
                model_input=input_transformed,
                model_output=scaler_autoencoder_wrapper.predict(
                    context=None,
                    model_input=input_raw_example
                )
            ),
        )

and save the mlflow model in args.model_output.
Next, you access model in sweep_step.outputs.model_output and
artifacts in sweep_step.outputs.artifacts.
The same thing is done in azure sample code which you have given.
    mlflow.sklearn.save_model(model, "model")

    from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree

    # copy subdirectory example
    from_directory = "model"
    to_directory = args.model_output

    copy_tree(from_directory, to_directory)

After saving the mlflow model in the folder model, all the files inside is copied to the output folder given args.model_output.
But i have given directly the path to save instead of copy.

thanks a lot for your help, I followed your Feedback plus many more approach but I still having the same issue.

What are the paths you have given to model_output and artifacts?

Also try save the models instead of logging. mlflow.keras.save_model

--model_output_path ${{outputs.model_output}}
--artifacts_output_path ${{outputs.artifacts_output}}
model_output: type: mlflow_model &  artifacts_output: type: uri_folder ....
I did that saved the Sklearn Object and Model as pkl and h5 and saved ont artifacts_ouputs (it works) , then  create another component to load the model, evaluate on some data and register the model (depending on the evaluation output)

Yes you give the same output path to next component to evaluate. are you able see the files saved in that location?

yes i am but only if I save them as file_folder and  .h5 format but if I use mlflow keras.log_model or pyfunc wapper I got that error. I decided to save the file into a dir and then re build the model ..Thanks a lot

For saving like mlflow you give model inout of type mlflow. which is defined in component output section. outputs:
model_output:
type: mlflow_model  Here, the model will be saved as mlflow to the given path.

For saving like mlflow you give model inout of type mlflow. which is defined in component output section. outputs: model_output: type: mlflow_model Here, the model will be saved as mlflow to the given path   ---  In Response: This seems to work with ---  anymodel.log_model default method ---  but when you create pyfunc custom wrapper it gives lot of error , or maybe is the sweep Job itself as it runs several trials at the same time , who knows I already asked Microsoft hoping they can provide more documentation

your custom wrapper object should have predict method and needs to inherit  mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel check this condition. Also refer this documentation for custom logging https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-log-mlflow-models?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=wrapper#logging-custom-models
